# need some help for centering login form

Tags: html, css

I have loggin form and I'd like it to position to center of the page. My code is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style>
    div.ex
    {
        width:300px;
        padding:10px;
        border:5px solid gray;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }

    .align {
        position: absolute;
        left: 8em;
    }
</Style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ex">
<h1>签订</h1>
<hr>
${errorMessage}
<form action="register" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>
            ID：
            <input type="text" name="id" value="${person.id}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            密码：
            <input type="password" name="password" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            确认密码：
            <input type="password" name="password" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            姓名：
            <input type="text" name="name" value="${person.name}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            地址：
            <input type="text" name="address" value="${person.address}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            电话：
            <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" value="${person.phoneNumber}" class="align"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="注册"/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything is now position at the center except all text field are positioned outside the login boxes.

I appreciate if someone could help me the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the rule of `div.ex`:

```
position:relative;
```

By establishing a new positioning context all child elements which have `position:absolute` are now positioned relatively to this div instead of the body of the page.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ewP22/).